# Laravel blade prefix the source with tab

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In the pages web browser's source I have the following tab prefix:

[image]

I checked out the `main.blade.php` which is the main layout template, but it has no any initial tabs or white spaces:

[image]

I don't know why this tab is rendered?!
I'm using [laravel-5.4](/questions/tagged/laravel-5.4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be the BOM (byte order mark)

Read more here: https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-byte-order-mark

Comment: Is there any way to ,clearly, identify this on Linux? Yes I have started the application on Windows, but I had migrated to Linux later. Currently I use VS Code as an IDE on Kubuntu 20.04.

Comment: `hexdump -n 3 -C yourfile`, should output `00000000  EF BB BF` which is the UTF-8 hex representation.